I'm unable to split a face in half
I've ran into a bit of a topology problem while modeling a pedestrian traffic light.
If you look at the image below, I'm trying to split the selected face in half:

I've tried subdividing, I've tried various solutions but I seem to be at an impasse. All I need help with is splitting the selected face in two to continue modeling the traffic light screens.
The blender file is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1z1FW2_EHKVPei6IZv-eFnfWpf6hBjK6c/view?usp=sharing
The link to the tutorial I was following & where I got stuck: https://youtu.be/J_FcEbHd8Bk?si=n_turkbIej6coZt-&t=1052
All help is appreciated.

First thing dissolve the existing edge with X (Delete) > Edges, then use J or the Knfie

You need the Knife operation (Hit k in edit mode).
Select the start and end of the cut, press enter.

It's not having any effect, the faces are still a single face. I've tested the Knife operation on other parts and it's working, but for some reason this split I'm trying to make isn't happening.

Maybe just delete that face, it might be duplicated or folded. Make another with "fill" (f) by selecting the contour edges

This way the inner non-manifold triangular face is still there, which is the reason of the J tool not working properly and might cause problems later as well.

You have messed up geometry there, I do not know what exactly you did or were trying to do. But first of all, when you select the front face, the edge in the center is not selected - which means it is not built from the vertices that built the face.

Hiding the front face by pressing H you can see there is an inner triangular face - this belongs to the visible unselected edge. Select and delete this triangle.

Then unhide the front face with Alt+H. The edge is gone.

Switch to Vertex Select mode and select those two opposing vertices in the center of the large face.

Now hit J to connect the vertices which will automatically split the face.

Afterwards you can select the top and bottom face separately.

However there are a lot of unnecessary vertices which do not serve any purpose. I would select them and hit X > Dissolve Vertices. And looking at the reference image of the traffic lights, I do not think that the mesh is supposed to be moved sideways... and I do not know if it is intentionally unconnected to the mesh in the back. I guess I would just delete this part and start doing it again.
